# Using Last_Value Window Function in Redshift/PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
select
    x.value1,
    x.value2,
    y,
    last_value(y ignore nulls)
          over (order by x.value1, x.value2 rows unbounded preceding) as val

from table t
```

For the following table,

```
value1.x1   value2.x2    3
value1.x2   value2.x2
value1.x3   value2.x3    5
value1.x4   value2.x4
value1.x5   value2.x5
value1.x6   value2.x6    7
value1.x7   value2.x7
```

the query is giving the output

```
value1.x1   value2.x2    3     3
value1.x2   value2.x2          3
value1.x3   value2.x3    5     5
value1.x4   value2.x4          5
value1.x5   value2.x5          5
value1.x6   value2.x6    7     7
value1.x7   value2.x7
```

It's correctly copying the values until the very last row. I'm not sure why it's not going all the way down. Is "rows unbounded preceding" not the correct frame to use? Can someone point out my mistake? Not sure if this would apply to MySQL as well but I would be interested in such a solution as well.

Thanks!

Comment: your query doesn't have a FROM clause, it uses x both as a column and as a table alias, it mentions 4 columns - x, y, value1 and value2, but your table data has only 2 column... 
how do you expect to get help? 
Provide DDL, sample INSERT statements, and the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should do what you want with the window specification.  However, an alternative method is to use `lag()`:

```
select x.value1, x.value2, y,
       (case when y is not null then y
             else lag(y ignore nulls) over (order by x.value1, x.value2)
        end) as val
from table t;
```